# Unix to find exact match of string

Tags: unix

I'm looking to find a way to match an exact string

for example:
I have these cmd that I run on unix server

1.)find ./ -name "*.jsp" -type f -exec grep -m1 -l '50.000' {} + >> 50dotcol.txt

2.)find ./ -name "*.jsp" -type f -exec grep -m1 -l '\<50.000>' {} + >> 50dotcol.txt*

Edited after Georges response:
find ./ -name "*.jsp" -type f -exec grep -m1 -l '(50.000)' {} + >> 50dotcol.txt

Still didn't pull in any results

The first one will find any string containing "50" the second will omit double digit strings but will pull in $50,000 $50.000. But I'm just looking to pull in "50.000" and that's it, no other variations of this

Am I missing something in my find cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
grep -m1 -l '(50\.000)'
```

instead.  That backslash before the < interprets it literally, which you don't want to do.  And you need to use parenthesis to have it considered as an exact group of characters.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've updated my command to include your suggestion, but when running it I didn't get any results. I've updated my cmd above, am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing with that exec, I generally use xargs to convert the stdout of one command to command line args of another.  Which in this case gives find . -name "*.jsp" |xargs grep '50\.000'  >> 50dotcol.txt